# EJB singleton on glassfish cluster

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb-3.1

Is it possible to create an EJB singleton across a glassfish cluster environment ?
I need a single instance for the entire cluster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EJB 3.1 singleton in cluster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375764/ejb-3-1-singleton-in-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

I think EJB Singleton will be replicated (like EJB Statefull) across Cluster nodes.

BUT it is impossible to have a single instance for the entire cluster. a singleton instance per Server instance.